# How to dispatch an action to change the inner state in a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Can I dispatch an action in the redux to change the inner state of a react component?

I have a state managed by the react state and I want to do some async stuff in the middleware of redux so that I can manage all the side effect in only one place. However, I want to change the inner state of react after I finished my async call and I don't want to manage this state by redux(You will need to pass too many things into the actions). Is there a way to fire up an action to change the react state by redux? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle hook.

So, you should connect to the updates using `connect` from `react-redux` and then update your local state.

For example:

**SomeContainer.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { yourCustomAsyncAction } from '../actions';
import SomeComponent from './components';

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    someValue: state.someState.someValue
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { yourCustomAsyncAction })(SomeComponent));
```

**SomeComponent.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class SomeComponent extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);

     this.state = {
       someLocalValue: '',
     }
   }

   componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
       // someValue - value which we passed from redux in container
       const { someValue } = nextProps;

      if (someValue !== this.state.someLocalValue) {
          this.setState({ someLocalValue: someValue });
      }
   }

   render() {
      return <div> Here will be updated value via Redux: {this.state.someLocalValue} </div>
   }

}

export default SomeComponent;
```

**NOTE:** `componentWillReceiveProps` is going to be deprecated starting with React version 16.3 (which should be released soon) and will be removed with 17 version. The new static method is introduced named `getDerivedStateFromProps`. See more [here](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0006-static-lifecycle-methods.md#new-static-lifecycle-methods).

Hope it will helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to set the state: idx + 1 after I have finished my async function. it seems that I can keep a variable such as 'isLoaded' in the redux to keep track of whether I have successfully finish my async function. But I don't know how to set the state based on this.

Comment: @leuction In this case you just can make this in `componentWillReceiveProps`:

    `if (nextProps.isLoaded)` then do `this.setState((prevState) => ({ idx: prevState.idx + 1 }))`;

But why you can't just keep this idx in the `Redux` store itself and just use it as prop in your Component? You're trying to do something tricky :)

Comment: Because I want to show different view depends on whether idx is the last one. If I move the index into the redux. I will need to move everything into the redux. I just curious about is there any good way to handle that only with react instead of put everything into the redux.

Comment: I think `componentDidUpdate` is the more appropriate place to introduce side effects on prop changes.  If you read up on [https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops](getderivedstatefromprops) you'll see that it's use isn't highly encouraged and that you should seek out simpler solutions.  With `componentDidUpdate` you get access to both the previous state and props.